# GST RTSP server - missing reference timestamp metadata

Tags: server, timestamp, metadata, gstreamer, rtsp

I want to use RTSP server for serving videos from camera(s). In my solution I need to provide exact capture timestamp for each of the video frames. For this I wanted to use the GstReferenceTimestampMeta struct. From the server side the code looks like that:

```
  GstCaps *imCaps = gst_caps_new_empty_simple("stream/x-timestamp");
  gst_buffer_add_reference_timestamp_meta (buffer, imCaps, timeStamp, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);
```

Everything seems fine - I'm able to get the reference timestamp metadata further in the server GST pipeline correctly, but from the client perspective it seems there is no such metadata (other fields like PTS or DTS have correct values):

```
  gst_buffer_get_reference_timestamp_meta(buffer, imCaps);  // returns NULL on client side
```

In the gstreamer logs I didn't see any obvious messages that indicate a problem with sending the GstReferenceTimestampMeta.

Do you know if my observations are expected, i.e. the GstReferenceTimestampMeta is ignored somewhere in the RTSP server <-> client path? I would appreciate any suggestions on this topic.

Thanks,
Tomasz